# Convert sentence into Pig Latin in C++

Tags: c++, apache-pig

I'm a beginner and I cannot figure out an efficient or not overly complicated way make this program work.

I need to take a sentence in the form of an array (via cin.getline) and write a function that converts it into pig latin in a second array.

I have the input done and the size of the second array set, but I'm having trouble in that I can't think of a way to make find the start of the words in the original array, convert it, and put it into the new array without making a loop that contains a switch statement where each case contains a bunch of nested loops.

I have to create all of my functions myself without using a string library file.

Any help, suggestions, ideas, or examples would be appreciated.

edit:

Yes, this is a university assignment, but I don't need the answer I just need to be steered in the proper direction because I'm out of ideas.

I've been trying to use a loop to find the start of each word and then check whether or not the first letter of the word is a vowel or consonant and then use loop or a nested loop to shift things and put it into the new array but I end up making it more complicated. Like, I use a loop to find the start of a word then a HUGE switch statement to decide whether or not if's a vowel or a consonant and then I end up with each case being some kind of new nested loop that I need to not overwrite itself later in the larger loop.

Comment: "Without the use of the string library" is an utterly retarded restriction. You should consider changing your employer if they insist on this.

Comment: Please post some of your code and somebody will help you to improve it.

Comment: Yep, this definitely sounds like an assignment given by an *employer*.

Comment: @KerrekSB and if this is a university?:D

Comment: What's the algorithm/process for converting a given sentence into 'pig latin'? Can you break it down into concise, repeatable steps?

Comment: @RomanB.: As a four-month active SO member, the OP would surely know better than not mark homework questions with the appropriate tag. :-) I'm giving her the benefit of the doubt and assume that this is a serious question.

Comment: Did you try google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851351/tokenizing-and-converting-to-pig-latin

Comment: (The actual answer of course involves `std::getline`, `std::istringstream` and `substr()`, but it's impossible to tell whether that will suit your constraints.)

Answer (score 3):

OK, a few random ideas:

1. To piglatinze a word: if first letter is a vowel, trivial; if not, find the first vowel. Split the string into two parts; output second part plus first part plus "ay".
2. To find a consonant, just test for "not a vowel". Basically, you only need one `is_vowel()` function.
3. Use `std::string`. Anything else you'd be doing would *not* be learning C++.

Leave a comment if you want spoilers.